# Need help to run a python function with GPU from pycharm or jupyter notebook

Tags: python, pycharm, numba

i have created a python function that basically generates images with random pixels and saves them to a folder. Heres the code:

```
from PIL import Image
from pathlib import Path  # to create the folder to store the images
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time
import random
from random import randint

#creates backround images with random pixel values
#if i run it again the previous images remain because in their names i add current time

def create_random_bg(N):
    Path("bg_images").mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)  # creates the folder
    folder = "bg_images/"  # keep folder name here and use it to save the image
    for i in range(N):
        pixel_data = np.random.randint(
            low=0,
            high=256,
            size=(1024, 1024, 3),
            dtype=np.uint8
        )

        img = Image.fromarray(pixel_data, "RGB")  # turn the array into an image
        img_name = str("bg_") + str(i) + str(time.time()) + str(".png")  # give a unique name using current time
        img = img.save(folder + img_name)

create_random_bg(100)
```

I want to run this code with my GPU in either pycharm or my jupyter notebook. I have NVIDIA Geforce RTX 3050 laptop. Can anyone help?

I attempted to do something like this:

```
from PIL import Image
from pathlib import Path  # to create the folder to store the images
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time
import random
from random import randint
**from numba import jit, cuda**

#creates backround images with random pixel values
#if i run it again the previous images remain because in their names i add current time

@jit(target_backend='cuda') #code i addedd, here i made it bold for people to see easier
def create_random_bg(N):
    Path("bg_images").mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)  # creates the folder
    folder = "bg_images/"  # keep folder name here and use it to save the image
    for i in range(N):
        pixel_data = np.random.randint(
            low=0,
            high=256,
            size=(1024, 1024, 3),
            dtype=np.uint8
        )

        img = Image.fromarray(pixel_data, "RGB")  # turn the array into an image
        img_name = str("bg_") + str(i) + str(time.time()) + str(".png")  # give a unique name using current time
        img = img.save(folder + img_name)

if __name__=="__main__":
  create_random_bg(100)
```

and it gives errors. Heres some of them:

```
@jit(target_backend='cuda')
C:\Users\wwwsh\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\core\object_mode_passes.py:151: NumbaWarning: Function "create_random_bg" was compiled in object mode without forceobj=True.

File "diffraction_imgs_cuda_gpu.py", line 17:
def create_random_bg(N):
    <source elided>
    folder = "bg_images/"  # keep folder name here and use it to save the image
    for i in range(N):
    ^

  warnings.warn(errors.NumbaWarning(warn_msg,
C:\Users\wwwsh\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\core\object_mode_passes.py:161: NumbaDeprecationWarning: 
Fall-back from the nopython compilation path to the object mode compilation path has been detected, this is deprecated behaviour.
```

Comment: You cannot run any arbitrary CPU function on a GPU. GPUs are completely different architecture. You need to write a dedicated GPU kernel, transfer data from the host to the device and the other way and also read/write the file on the CPU because you cannot do that on the GPU (at least not that way).

Comment: Even if you could write a GPU kernel (clearly far from being easy for a beginner), the png file format is clearly not suited for GPUs anyway. GPU can only speed up some specific codes, not all parallel code (only SIMT-friendly ones with some additional restrictions). Not to mention your GPU is not particularly powerful even if it would be well suited and data transfer would certainly make the operation not very efficient anyway.

Comment: Put it shortly, it does not make sense to do that. Please read the Numba documentation and the CUDA documentation before asking such question (or the many previous SO posts about that).